# How to create a custom command or shortcut/symlink to run the standalone program?

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, symlink, tor

Friends I have downloaded tor bundle which is a standalone package. I'd like to create a custom command "torbrowser". I followed these steps,

--> I copied entire tor bundle to my `/usr/local` directory

--> I created a symlink of that `start-tor-browser.desktop` in `/usr/bin` which is in `$PATH` with the name torbrowser

when I tried to run `torbrowser`, it is throwing `command not found`. And when I try to run `/usr/bin/torbrowser` it is throwing `permission denied`. And when I tried using `sudo /usr/bin/torbrowser`, it says `command not found`. And alias works but with sudo. Tor doesn't work with sudo.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/torbrowser` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've just forget to make `torbrowser` executable.

`sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/torbrowser`

Comment: thank you, after seeing your answer i tried to do in CentOS. It is throwing an error `chmod: cannot access ‘/sbin/start-tor-browser.desktop’: Too many levels of symbolic links` . I also tried the above path with same error `cannot access ‘/usr/bin/start-tor-browser.desktop’: Too many levels of symbolic links` . Please let me know for any more solutions.